# Parsing DecimalFormat to avoid scientific notation

Tags: java, android

I need parsing a number, String value = "15000000"

```
Public static String FormatValue(value){
    double formatedValue= Double.parseDouble(value);        

    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');       
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("# ### ### ### ###.##", dfs);
    df.format(valorAformatear);
    return  String.valueOf(formatedValue);  
}
```

I need the return value to be "15 000 000.00" BUT, When I call the method returns, "7.5E7", how can I avoid the scientific notation?

Comment: Use a DecimalFormat to format your number as a string, in the format you want. Your code doesn't compile. Show your real code.

Answer (score 2):

You ignored the return of the [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) method and instead returned the normal conversion to a `String` using `String.valueOf`.  The `format` method doesn't change the number; it returns its formatted representation.  Also, `String.valueOf` will use scientific notation if the number is large enough.

Just return what `format` returns.